NFT Contract Address shows NULL value
I am new to blockchain development.
I am facing one issue in deploy.js, while running npx hardhat run src/backend/scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
ideally, it should show something like
Deploying contracts with the account: value
Account balance: value
NFT CONTACT ADDRESS value

but it is returning
Deploying contracts with the account: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
Account balance: 9999992459571303767619n
NFT CONTACT ADDRESS undefined

i'd like to know how to fix this undefined issue, please help

deploy.js code

async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  
    console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);
    console.log("Account balance:", await deployer.provider.getBalance(deployer.address));
  
    
    // Get the ContractFactories and Signers here.
    const NFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFT");
    const nft = await NFT.deploy();
    // Save copies of each contracts abi and address to the frontend.
    console.log("NFT CONTACT ADDRESS",nft.address)
    saveFrontendFiles(nft , "NFT");
    
  }
  
  function saveFrontendFiles(contract, name) {
    const fs = require("fs");
    const contractsDir = __dirname + "/../../frontend/contractsData";
  
    if (!fs.existsSync(contractsDir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(contractsDir);
    }
  
    fs.writeFileSync(
      contractsDir + `/${name}-address.json`,
      JSON.stringify({ address: contract.address }, undefined, 2)
    );
  
    const contractArtifact = artifacts.readArtifactSync(name);
  
    fs.writeFileSync(
      contractsDir + `/${name}.json`,
      JSON.stringify(contractArtifact, null, 2)
    );
  }
  
  main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      process.exit(1);
    });


Issue is fixed:
async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);
  console.log("Account balance:", (await ethers.provider.getBalance(deployer.address)).toString());

  const NFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFT");
  console.log("Deploying NFT contract...");
  const nft = await NFT.deploy();

  console.log("Waiting for deployment...");
  // Wait for the contract to be mined
  await nft.waitForDeployment();

  const nftAddress = await nft.getAddress();
  console.log("NFT CONTRACT ADDRESS", nftAddress);
  saveFrontendFiles(nft, "NFT");
}

async function saveFrontendFiles(contract, name) {
  const fs = require("fs");
  const contractsDir = __dirname + "/../../frontend/contractsData";
  if (!fs.existsSync(contractsDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(contractsDir);
  }

  const contractAddress = await contract.getAddress();
  console.log("Contract address:", contractAddress);

  const addressData = JSON.stringify({ address: contractAddress }, undefined, 2);
  console.log("Address data to be written:", addressData);

  const filePath = contractsDir + `/${name}-address.json`;
  console.log("Writing to file:", filePath);

  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, addressData);
    console.log("File written successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error writing file:", error);
  }

  const contractArtifact = artifacts.readArtifactSync(name);
  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/${name}.json`,
    JSON.stringify(contractArtifact, null, 2)
  );
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

